# reading sqlite database using java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have an sqlite database file named sample.db .
   Now i don't know its table names or in a broad way i don't know what it contains.
   So is there any way through which i can read its tables ?

Comment: Start by looking the [JDBC(TM) Database Access tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/), you can access the database meta-data to get a list of the tables

Comment: There is a tutorial here at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm